# ActiveMQ consumer groups on Pub/Sub topics

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, publish-subscribe

I'm quite new to the ActiveMQ and I would like to know if it's possible to setup for the following scenario:

Service A and B subscribe to a Pub/Sub topic. This topic I use for event sending, so the interested service can react on it.

Now, if I want to scale the service A, adding one more instance. How can I ensure that both instance won't process the same event? (Ending up create duplicated data).

Is it possible to achieve this in ActiveMQ? If yes, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using JMS then this scenario really needs *shared* topic subscriptions which were [added in JMS 2.0](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jms2messaging.html). ActiveMQ 5.x doesn't support JMS 2, but [ActiveMQ Artemis](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/) (the next generation ActiveMQ broker) does support JMS 2 so you should use that.

Answer (score 1):

Vitor Villar you can also use Virtual Topics in ActiveMQ 5.x Virtual Topics are effectively the holy grail of messaging-- you publish to a topic and consume from queues.

1. Producers and consumers are not linked to the same address (queue or topic name)
2. Consumers can use all consuming patterns-- multi-threaded, active-standby, and message groups

ref: [Virtual Topic](https://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations)

Comment: Virtual Topics are a potential solution, but they're are unique to ActiveMQ 5.x. In other words, they are not portable. If you want a standards-based, portable solution that you can count on to be able to use with other (JMS2) brokers then shared topic subscriptions are a good solution. I've seen a lot of users build their architectures around Virtual Topics because they are powerful (as you note), but then they are stuck on ActiveMQ 5.x. Given that ActiveMQ Artemis is slated to replace ActiveMQ 5.x such an investment into a 5.x-specific architecture may not be wise.

Comment: For now I think the Virtual Topic would be the best option. What’s the equivalent to Virtual Topic in the ActiveMQ Artemis?

Comment: If you want a solution based on a standard specification then I would recommend JMS 2's shared topic subscriptions as I already described in my answer. If you implement a solution based on Virtual Topics in 5.x now then you can [migrate it to ActiveMQ Artemis later](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/openwire.html#virtual-topic-consumer-destination-translation). The underlying architecture of ActiveMQ Artemis already supports these kinds of semantics. In general, it is more powerful and flexible than the primarily JMS-centric configuration of 5.x.

Comment: 2 things-- The virtual topic pattern is not unique to ActiveMQ 5.x.  IBM MQ supports the exact same pattern. Also, how is it not standards compliant? The producer and consumer code are both written to the JMS API.

Comment: My point about virtual topics not being standard isn't so much about adherence to the JMS API but the fact that the *behavior* is non-standard. Virtual topics allow a JMS application to send to a topic and consume from a queue. You can use the JMS API to do this, but the behavior doesn't conform to JMS. I understand that some other brokers employ similar semantics. This is even possible in ActiveMQ Artemis using FQQN. However, it's not something that would be easily portable to another JMS provider that didn't employ such semantics. Using JMS 2 would solve that issue.